# Override widget styling

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to add to or override specific methods or properties of a widget, while still having access to the default properties. I can imagine this would come in useful when still wanting the full widget functionality but maybe adding a method or to provide defaults.

---

*For example:*

Lets say I want to style a container to have rounded corners:

Instead of doing this everywhere I want this style:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
)
```

I create a CustomRoundedDecoration class and default the borderRadius property:

```
class CustomRoundedDecoration extends BoxDecoration {
  RoundedDecoration( /* somehow keep all BoxDecoration properties */ )

  @override
  BorderRadiusGeometry get borderRadius => BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)); // my default
}
```

Then I can just use my new CustomRoundedDecoration, but most importantly **still have access to the default BoxDecoration properties**, and potentially still override the borderRadius.

```
decoration: CustomRoundedDecoration(/* access other BoxDecoration properties but now I've got borderRadius defaulted */),
```

Obviously in practice you would add or override many properties, not just the one.

---

I know it is possible to copy the source code into your own widget and change whats needed there, but this seems a bit overkill to just provide defaults

Comment: Extending widgets is discouraged. Either embed them, or if this does not provide the functionality you need, create a custom derivative or create a Pull Request that adds the desired configurability.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. Could you explain how extending built in widgets is worse than building your own? Is it merely the fact that you are extending unused properties and methods, adding unnecessary bloat?